# Check if mouse is down on a mouseout event- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I want to know if a user stops pressing a button.  So I capture the $button.mouseup(...) and $button.mouseout(...) events.  However, I want the mouseout event to only matter when the user is still pressing the mouse- Otherwise, it will fire whenever the user passes over the button.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can just set a global variable to `true` on mousedown and get that value on `mouseout`.

Answer (score 8):

Check `e.which`, which indicates the pressed button.

Comment: Beautiful, that helped me out so much.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty method would be to use globals (or closures; some way of giving both the `mouseup` and the `mouseout` functions access to the same variable):

```
var mouseIsUp = true,
    onMouseUp = function () {
        mouseIsUp = true;
        // ...
    },
    onMouseDown = function () {
        mouseIsUp = false;
    },
    onMouseOut = function () {
        if (!mouseIsUp) {
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work in the case that the mouse has moved out of the original element between the mousedown and mouseup events.

Comment: @Alnitak I think I typo'd the conditional check. Is that what you were talking about?